# How to fix NoClassdefFoundError

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm a newbie with both android and eclipse, so if you can help me, please don't assume that I know very much.

I have downloaded kankan.wheel and I'm trying to run the demos.  I built the demo project in eclipse, using Android project from existing code. The project compiles without error, but crashes with a NoClassdefFoundError exception when I try to run it.  The main menu comes up, but when I press a button to run a demo, the app crashes. I posted a screenshot of the the error message in context at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24746182/except.png

I have added the wheel.jar file to the assets folder, and placed it on the build path.  I've also checked wheel.jar in Order and Export.  (This makes no sense to me, but I see this suggested in answer to similar questions.)

What have I done wrong, or failed to do?

Is there some reason why eclipse wouldn't just build a runnable project?

This is an update after trying the suggestion people have made.  I still can't get it to work, so I'm afraid that I'm overlooking something so obvious that no one's thinking to tell me.  Here is what I did.

1. I downloaded and unrarer a rar file with the wheel library and a wheel-demo project.
2. I created the wheel-demo project in eclipse, using new android project from existing cde.
3. I added a libs folder to my project, and copied wheel.jar into it.
4. I right-clicked on the wheel-demo project in Project Explorer, and chose java build path.
5. I clicked on "Add external jar" and navigated to wheel.jar.
6. I went to "Order and Export" and checked wheel.jar.

I had several errors.  In the .java file for each activity (except the main activity), I got an error on the line
import kankan.wheel.R;

I commented this line out.

Also, since wheel.jar apparently doesn't specify a minimum API level, I got a error, but I just put a minimum sdk level of 8 in the manifest.  I was then able to build the project without error.  Still, the main screen comes up, but the app crashes as before when I press a button for any activity.

Can you see anything I've left out or done wrong?

Comment: try checking android private libraries under order export tab if you have updated adt to rev 22. clean and build. for further help post some code

Comment: I don't see anything labeled "private libraries" on the order and export tab.  Is this where I have neglected to do something? As for posting code, I didn't write any.  This is a widely-used third party library, according to my understanding.

Comment: try the answer below. you should copy the jar to your libs folder of your project. I am not aware of the library coz i have not used the same. But generally you copy the jars to your libs folder

Comment: Thanks you.  Please look at my last comment to the answer below.  It now seems clear that the WheelView class is being found, but one of the drawables it needs is not.  Do you think perhaps I need to rebuild the jar file from the sources?

Answer (score 2):

Try to place your jar file to the 'libs' folder at the project root

Comment: Thanks.  I did that to begin with, with the same result.  Then I read an answer that said it should go in the assets folder, so I moved it.

Comment: It looks like you need to add kankan project as a dependency, not just a jar file. Check if this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258512/jar-file-for-kankan-wheel

Comment: I've found some more information.  I added the source folder to the lookup path in eclipse, and I see that the WheelView code is actually being executed.  However, I'm getting an InvocationTargetException on one of the drawables.  I looked for that drawable in the download, and it's definitely on the disk, in res/drawable.   Does this suggest anything?

Comment: The problem is, that you`ve added to the eclipse path some folders, which doesn't get to the device actually. Basically, you have to check the following steps: 1) make sure, that the kankan project is connected as dependency; 2) check you 'project.properties' file to contain kankan dependency.

Comment: The jar file contains only 'class' files. All the assets go from the dependency.

Answer (score 1):

I was never able to get it to work with the rar file.  Here is what worked;

1. svn checkout http://android-wheel.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ android-wheel-read-only
2. import wheel project into eclipse
3. fix the android:targetSdkVersion version in the manifest to get rid of the "unable to resolve target android-7" error
4. build the wheel project as a library
5. import wheel-demo project into eclipse
6. fix the skdVersion in the manifest
7. change "import android.wheel.R" to "import android.wheel.demo.R" in all the source files where it occurs.
8. build the wheel-demo project

I may have left out a minor detail or two.